# Matrix transformations, Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

**Question:**

---

Consider the matrix:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2 \\
    2 & 0     
\end{bmatrix}$$
(i) Determine the two eigenvalues, and the normalised eigenvectors

(ii)Establish whether the eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other, or not

(iii)Write the normalised eigenvectors into the columns of a matrix D, and show that the inverse matrix $D^{-1}$ us given by its transpose $D^{T}$.
Hint: compute the matrix product $D .D^T$

(iv) Show that the matrix:
$$M=D.M.D^{-1}$$
is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal

(v)Consider the matrix

$$N=\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2 \\
    2 & 0     
\end{bmatrix}$$
Show that N is the inverse matrix to M, and that the eigenvectors of M are also eigenvectors of N, and read off the eigenvalues.

---

**My Attempt**

---

$$M\vec{e}=\mu \vec{e}$$
where $\vec{e}$ is an eigenvector and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue.
$$A\vec{e}-\mu I \vec{e}=0,$$
$$(A-\mu I) \vec{e}=0.$$
If $\vec{e}$ is non-zero then this means that the columns of $A-\mu I$ are linearly dependent. Hence
$$det(A-\mu I)=0,$$
$$det(A-\mu I)= \begin{vmatrix}
    -\mu & 2 \\
    2 & -\mu     
\end{vmatrix}$$
From this, we see that:
$$\mu=\pm 2,$$ these are the eigen values.

To find the associated eigenvectors, I re-substitute these back into:
$$(A-\mu I) \vec{e}=0.$$
For $\mu$=2, we get:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 \\
    2 & -2     
\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    y_1    
\end{bmatrix}=0$$
For $\mu$=-2, we get:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2 \\
    2 & 2     
\end{bmatrix} .\begin{bmatrix}
    x_2 \\
    y_2    
\end{bmatrix}=0$$
For $\mu=2$, this is the same as writing:
$$-2x_1+2y_1=0,$$
$$2x_1-2y_1=0.$$
here, we see that an eigenvector satisfying both of these are:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    y_1    
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1    
\end{bmatrix}$$
For $\mu=-2$, this is the same as writing:
$$2x_2+2y_2=0,$$
$$2x_2+2y_2=0.$$
here, we see that an eigenvector satisfying both of these are:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_2 \\
    y_2    
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1    
\end{bmatrix}$$
and to normalise them I can just put $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in front of both of them.

**Problem #1**

Although I think I am right with these eigenvectors **it does confuse me** that I could flip the signs round and still have an eigenvector that satisfies my equations, for example in the case where $\mu=-2$ surely the eigenvector could just as easily be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_2 \\
    y_2    
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1    
\end{bmatrix}$$
I understand that when I normalise the vector, I am essentially making it a unit vector... but surely flipping the signs as I have just now would flip the direction of the unit vector, essentially making it a different one. I am thinking that it is my decision as to what I do with this, as I would be choosing them for the base of a new co-ordinate system, but I was hoping someone could verify whether or not I am correct in thinking this.

Part(ii) I don't have a problem with (just use dot product)

Part(iii) I have generated the matrix:
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}     
\end{bmatrix}$$
By simply putting the eigenvectors in  the columns of the matrix.
I have computed the inverse of the matrix, by the following method:
$$\frac{1}{det(D)}*Adj{D}$$
$$D^{-1}=-1. \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}     
\end{bmatrix}$$
OR
$$ D^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}     
\end{bmatrix}$$

Howver, If we consider the transpose of the matrix D, we get that:
$$D^T=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}     
\end{bmatrix}$$
**Problem #2**

**I have clearly gone wrong, as by my calculation $D^{-1}$ is not equal to $D^T$**
I was wondering if anyone could spot my mistake, as I have repeated it several times I can not see. Also, I am unsure why the question has told me to compute $D^{-1}*D^{T}$, perhaps this is some identity that I am unaware of?

**Problem 3**

For the other two questions I was just wondering if someone could let me know what would be sufficient to satisfy the 'show that', can i simply computw the matrix multiplication of $D.M.D^{-1}$? and the same for part (v). Basically I am asking if there are any Identities that would allow me to show it without computing it all.

Sorry for the long post, but I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1: when you change the sign, what you get is a vector that is collinear to the one you had. Therefore there is no problem at all, you know that eigenspaces are linear subspaces.

Problem #2: there is a sign issue when you compute $D^{-1}$, at the very first step. Adj means the transpose of the comatrix.

Problem #3: (iv) you can avoid computing the product by using the fact that the columns of $D$ are eigenvectors. Hint: the first column of a matrix $M$ is in fact $M\cdot \left(\matrix{1\\0} \right)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have re-attempted to calculate the inverse matrix of D, I have gotten: $D=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}   
\end{bmatrix}$. I think that I am getting the cofactor matrix part incorrect: $Co-factor=\begin{bmatrix}
    + & - & + \\
   - & + & - \\   
  + & - & + \end{bmatrix}$ I have applied this to D to get: $D_{cofactor}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}   
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: As a rule of thumb, for 2x2 matrices switch the diagonal elements and change the sign of the other two.

Comment: oh ok, so it means I change the sign to a plus, rather than just applying it in front of it?

Comment: I have again re-attempted to calculate the inverse matrix of D, by your method: I have flipped the signs of the diagonal elements to get: $D_{cofactor}=\begin{bmatrix}
   - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}   
\end{bmatrix}$. This leads to the correct proof. However I don't understand why I can just flip the signs. I was under the impression that to get the cofactor matrix, I simply 'overlay' the following matrix  $Co-factor=\begin{bmatrix}
    + & - & + \\
   - & + & - \\   
  + & - & + \end{bmatrix}$ with D

Comment: The Adj operation is the composition of three things: replace every entry by the opposite minor (which here is the opposite entry), multiply by the alternating signs with the pattern that you indicated, and then transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1 and #2, your $AdjD$ step has a mistake, all signs should be negative except for the bottom right